# ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because: services.mysql.ports is invalid

Tags: mysql, laravel, docker

**ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because: services.mysql.ports is invalid: Invalid port ""3307":3306", should be [[remote_ip:]remote_port[-remote_port]:]port[/protocol]**

Using docker with Laravel sail on Laravel v8.7
trying to create a external port in Digital ocean droplet Ubuntu 20.04
Want to use multiple projects in one droplet in order to do that using separate containers but facing this issue.
**docekr-compsoer.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
    laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.1
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.1/app
        extra_hosts:
            - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
            XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}'
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - mysql
    mysql:
        image: 'mysql/mysql-server:8.0'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: "%"
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
        volumes:
            - 'sailmysql:/var/lib/mysql'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-p${DB_PASSWORD}"]
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    sailmysql:
        driver: local
```

** .env **

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:4KqkfLTvVorxQCcZMHxmxxUcmeg3JKNoMNfDbyVWSd8=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

APP_PORT="8080"
FORWARD_DB_PORT="3307"

//rest of the configs
```

Comment: Try changing `FORWARD_DB_PORT="3307"` to `FORWARD_DB_PORT=3307`

Answer (score 0):

In docker-compose, the rule for mapping ports is as follows.

```
remote_ip:remote_port:port
```

But you misplaced the variables.
Modify the syntax as follows:

```
ports:
    - ${APP_PORT}:80

ports:
    - ${FORWARD_DB_PORT}:3306
```

And in the dotenv file, for variables of Integer type, you do not need to double quote, correct them as well.

```
APP_PORT=8080
FORWARD_DB_PORT=3307
```

Comment: the issue was just double quotes, if you do not define ports in dotenv file then it takes default external port as 80 in this case - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'

Answer (score 0):

The error you're encountering is due to an incorrect format in the docker-compose.yml file, specifically in the definition of the ports for the MySQL service.

In Docker Compose, the ports syntax should be [HOST]:[CONTAINER], where [HOST] is the port on the host machine and [CONTAINER] is the port inside the container.

To fix this issue, need need to remove "" from the `.env` file:

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:4KqkfLTvVorxQCcZMHxmxxUcmeg3JKNoMNfDbyVWSd8=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost
APP_PORT=8080
FORWARD_DB_PORT=3307
//rest of the configs
```